# Vsplit causes vertical scrollbars to be displayed (gvim)

Tags: vim

Making the transition from Vim to gVim, I would like to disable all toolbars and scrollbars. This works for the most part, but when I open a vertical split, under certain conditions, a scroll bar pops up on the left. If you open the second picture in a new tab, you can see my vim options for disabling the toolbars/menubars/scrollbars in the bottom right window. How do I get rid of them for good?

**Before:**

[image: Before the vsplit]

**After:**
[image: After the vsplit]

Comment: Btw, what are those light gray columns with "}>"s?

Comment: @ldigas I don't know. I remember them popping up a while ago after I installed a mod to show marks. I guess those are some kind of system specific marks. They change too as I move around. Quite ominous if you ask me

Comment: @ldigas Here is the link (I just removed the plugin by the way, almost completely useless) http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=152

Comment: Thought it might be something like that ... I think I actually used that plugin once before ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You show what you've *turned off* from your `guioptions` but not what remains. In any case, the solution's in there. I'd start with turning off both `r` and `R`, and `l` and `L`. If the problem persists, go with

```
set guioptions=
```

and then add an item one by one (those which you need)

```
set guioptions+=...
```

This is really the best way to *debug it* :)

I have only `=aem` in `guioptions`, and don't see any scrollbars or anything of the kind.

Comment: The issue was likely that you needed `set guioptions-=L`. Per `:h guioptions`, the default options are `aegimrLtT`. In your screenshot, you've removed `l` (which probably wasn't there anyway) but not `L`.